# I dont know what is wrong with my tkinter project

Tags: python, tkinter

it has worked in the past and i have no clue what has happened. please help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urSQn.png)

Comment: Your code does not run because it is an image. Post it as text so we can help you.

Comment: For a better experience install PyCharm and your Traceback error will show you the way.

Answer (score 2):

Close the parenthesis at the end of line, should be `y = 170))`.

When IDE with syntax highlighting isn't available, you might install `pylint` or other linter package to check your code. Linters could help  a lot.